# How do I split a string of numbers into numbered columns in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| ImageID | labels | caption_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.JPG | 1 | Woman in swim suit holding parasol |
| 1.JPEG | 1 19 | a black and silver clock tower |
| 2.JPEG | 8 3 13 | This photo shows people skiing in the mountains. |

The labels for this data set range from 1 to 19 and I am trying to allocate them to their own column. The final dataframe will have an additional 19 columns with a 1 or 0.

For example, "8 3 13" will have a 1 in columns 8, 3 and 13 and 0's everywhere else.

So far I have managed to put them into arrays and managed to put them into columns, but neither of these gives me what I need.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share a [reproducible code snippet of your dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) along with your code attempt as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already know the range to be 1-19, you can do a get_dummies and reindex:

```
n=19
arr = df['labels'].str.get_dummies(' ').reindex(map(str,range(1,n+1)),axis=1,fill_value=0)
print(arr)

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
2  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Finally you can concat this with the original dataframe:

```
out = pd.concat((df,arr),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to offer an alternative way of doing this. You can iterate over each of your labels and see if the value in `labels` contains that label:

```py
n = 19
for i in range(1, n+1):
    df[i] = df['labels'].str.contains(rf'\b{i}\b').astype(int)
```